# Dynamically set required fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, dynamic

I'm curious how I can dynamically set a model's validation attributes. For instance, I often have Views where certain fields should be required when a user is in a certain role, but not required when a user is in another role. I would like both the server-side and client-side validation to be set accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't something like this work for you for the server side?

```
public class RequiredForRoleAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string Role { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return !Roles.IsUserInRole(Role) || (value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value));
    }
}
```

And an example usage will be;

```
        [RequiredForRoleAttribute(Role = "Admins", ErrorMessage = "Phone number is required for members of the admin role.")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

Now for the client side of things,

Your going to have to register it for remote validation as described at the following link; http://forums.asp.net/t/1559594.aspx/1

Hope you get it,

Chris